# iPhone how to parse nested xml file and display in tableview

Tags: iphone, xml-parsing

I have the following xml file

```
<Root>
<propertytype value="Property1">
<property>
<Property_Name>Name</Property_Name>
</defaultValue>
</property>
<property>
<Property_Name>Address</Property_Name>
</defaultValue>
</property>
<property>
<Property_Name>Age</Property_Name>
</defaultValue>
</property>
</propertytype>
<propertytype value="Property2">
<property>
<Property_Name>Cell Number</Property_Name>
</defaultValue>
</property>
<property>
<Property_Name>E-mail</Property_Name>
</defaultValue>
</property>
</propertytype>
</Root>
```

What i need is propertytype attributes value need to display in tableview and whenever i click on that value say "Property1", the respective elements(Name,Address and Age) need to be displayed in other view

Please help me?

I used the NSXMLParser and code is pasted below

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qualifiedName 
    attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {



    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Root"]) {
        //Initialize the array.
        appDelegate.subtype = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        appDelegate.books = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];




    }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"propertytype"]) {




        sub=[[Subexptype alloc]init];

        //Extract the attribute here.

        sub.bookID=[attributeDict objectForKey:@"value"];

        NSLog(@"Reading id value :%@", sub.bookID);

        }
    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"property"]) {

        aBook = [[Book alloc] init];


    }




    NSLog(@"Processing Element: %@", elementName);
}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string { 

    if(!currentElementValue) 
        currentElementValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentElementValue appendString:string];

    NSLog(@"Processing Value: %@", currentElementValue);

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName 
  namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {



    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Root"])
        return;

    //There is nothing to do if we encounter the Books element here.
    //If we encounter the Book element howevere, we want to add the book object to the array
    // and release the object.

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"propertytype"]){


        [appDelegate.subtype addObject:sub];
        [sub release];
        sub=nil;
    }


    else if([elementName isEqualToString:@"property"]){
        [appDelegate.books addObject:aBook];


        [aBook release];
        aBook = nil;
    }
    else
        [aBook setValue:currentElementValue forKey:elementName];



    [currentElementValue release];
    currentElementValue = nil;
}
```

Now, i can able to get attribute value like "Property1" and "Property2" in tableview and whenever i click on Property1 or Property2 i get all elements like Name,Address,Age,E-mail and Cell Number.

But i don't want this way, if i click on Property1 its respective elements like Name, Address and Age shuold be displayed and if i click on property2 its elements Cell Number and E-mail shuold be displayed

Please help me where i am wrong

Comment: Try parsing using NSXMLParser and paste the code if you get stuck.

Comment: I added my code.Please help me

Comment: Can you even tell whats going wrong here? I mean whats the error you are encountering, so that the problem is narrowed down instead of reviewing the code.

Comment: I don't get any error, instead of displaying its respective elements all the elements are displayed

Comment: Hmm ok i will write an answer based on your code in sometime.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a class that contains Name,Address and Age and after parsing your file, you have to add each object in a NSMutableArray.
I idvise you for parsing your file to use TBXML library downloadable from http://www.tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html
Hoping find this useful

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
XMLReader.h
```

This will return you a dictionary for your xml.and from there you can easily extract the required content.

```
NSDictionary *_xmlDictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[XMLReader dictionaryForXMLData:responseData error:&error]];
```

Check the XMLReader class from here

http://dcraziee.wordpress.com/2013/05/29/parsing-xml-in-objective-c/